# About solving Arabic language in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

- I create a website with Arabic display. I test it in my local PC. It works fine
- Put when I uploaded it to company hosting.
- the Arabic language appeared as Symbols. Not in default format
- although the header contains supported Arabic language
- so anyone help me what is the problem

  ```
  <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" XML: lang="ar-sa" lang="ar-sa" dir="ltr" >
  <head>
   <meta HTTP-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  ```

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="ar-sa" lang="ar-sa" dir="ltr" >
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

Comment: Language doesn't matter. They are just characters as far as computers are concerned (at least for the purposes of this question). Character encoding matters. Make sure you are using an encoding that supports that characters you want and that you are using it from initial entry all the way through to the HTTP response that delivers it to the browser.

Comment: You would be better off deleting the comment you just posted with code in it and editing your question to include the code (and formatting it as code).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer, it is Arabic explanation 
http://www.citystarit.com/Article_details.aspx?id=69

I have saved as only the master page, but it didn't work with me , then I have saved all As all other pages and it worked fine

Comment: You should include the essential parts of the solution here, in case the link you gave goes out of date in the future.

Answer (score -1):

Very possible that the hosting machine lacks the Arabic language, and thus will not render it properly.

Comment: Lacks the Arabic language … where? *In its language packs?* That would only affect the ability to show the OS interface in Arabic. *In its fonts?* That would only affect its ability to render the page in a browser running on the server itself.

Comment: IIRC, if the server lacks the language packs, it won't be able to push the content hosted correctly.

Comment: As far as the server is concerned, they are (or at least should be) just UTF-8 characters. Language packs are irrelevant.